# Denied Access downloading file from google drive api

Tags: google-drive-android-api

How to upload a file using the google drive api and when the file is getting opened it will not show a restriction message and allow any user to open it.

For example I have this URL

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cvmvU-Tz66Z7x3ukHqLgoB9BY9pxftrn/view?usp=drivesdk

That was uploaded from the app but it got restricted.

Answer (score 0):

You have the control to [share files from Google Drive](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2494822?co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&hl=en&oco=1) and [upload files and folders to Google Drive](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2424368?hl=en&ref_topic=2429901&co=GENIE.Platform%3DAndroid&oco=1).

> You can share the files and folders that you store in Google Drive
>   with anyone in your work or school, but your organization may limit
>   how you can share files with other people.

Also, you can visit this [help forum post](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/drive/W9hH5Ct6xw8) on to what extent you can allow everyone to upload in your drive.

Additional reference: [Drive API Documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-uploads)